# How do I run the precompiled image of Rust-based Redox OS on Windows10 64-bit under QEMU emulator?

Tags: rust, qemu, redox-os

How do I run the precompiled image of Rust-based Redox OS on Windows10 64-bit with the QEMU emulator?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the Redox OS ISO drive image that will have the compiled OS image that QEMU will later execute.  Please obtain the latest release of the .ISO file from [here](https://gitlab.redox-os.org/redox-os/redox/tags) (click on download link for the latest release).
2. Mount the ISO image using a an [image mounter](https://www.elby.ch/en/products/vcd.html) that will be able to show the ISO image as a drive attached to the system allowing file access.
3. Copy LIVEDISK.gz file to your hard drive and extract the livedisk.bin file within.  This is the Redox bootable image via an emulator, in this case QEMU.
   [image]
4. Install latest version of precompiled QEMU images for Windows from [here](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/).
5. Read this interesting [blog tutorial](https://tw.saowen.com/a/5e934b2c3d6bba0765c4f87b6a9eeed7ee807fee157b0ab98590881b8905817a) here and install HAXM for Genuine Intel CPUs.
6. Execute QEMU from a DOS box using the following command (Fix to specify your proper directories):

---

```
C:\Program Files\qemu>qemu-system-x86_64 -serial mon:stdio -d cpu_reset -d guest_errors -smp 4 -m 1024 -s -machine q35 -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-duplex -net nic,model=e1000 -net user -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci -device usb-tablet,bus=xhci.0 -cpu qemu64 -drive file=C:\Users\redox\Documents\GitHub\redox\livedisk.bin,format=raw -accel hax
```

7. Follow instructions [here](https://doc.redox-os.org/book/getting_started/try_vm.html) to log into the Redox OS.  Enjoy!
   [image]

Notes: my mouse movement is super bad to the point of unusability.  Perhaps some massaging of the QEMU input device?  Not sure.  Any tips welcome :)

TIP: Install source with directions [here](https://doc.redox-os.org/book/getting_started/installing_the_toolchain.html).